# checkbox and input values are not being set in ngFor?

Tags: angular

I have an array that contains true/false values and some text.  When I do an ngFor on the array, the checkboxes aren't being checked and the value of the inputs aren't being set.  If I just show the values of the boolean and text via {{}}, I can see the values:

```
<tr *ngFor="let milestone of milestones">
             {{milestone.IsIncluded}} //I can see true or false
              <td><input [(ngModel)]="milestone.IsIncluded"  name="IsIncluded" type="checkbox"></td>
              <td>{{milestone.MilestoneTitle}}</td>
              <td>
                {{milestone.Name}} //I can see the name
                <input type="text" name="Name" [(ngModel)]="milestone.Name" class="form-control" />
              </td>
            </tr>
```

All the inputs are blank, it is not setting the value that comes from milestone.Name and all the checkboxes are unchecked even though the first two of the array have IsIncluded set to true.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It looks like in ngFor, I need to have a unique name for the inputs, so I did this:

```
   <tr *ngFor="let milestone of milestones;let in = index">
              <td><input [(ngModel)]="milestone.IsIncluded"  name="IsIncluded-{{in}}" type="checkbox"></td>
              <td>{{milestone.MilestoneTitle}}</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="Name-{{in}}" [(ngModel)]="milestone.Name" class="form-control" />
              </td>
            </tr>
```